# Can't run ckeditor:install

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor

Following along with the documentation found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/installation.html

I have currently entered the command:

`composer require egeloen/ckeditor-bundle`

which resolves currently to

> Using version ^5.0 for egeloen/ckeditor-bundle

After which, I enter the new package to my AppKernel and goto run the command:

`php bin/console ckeditor:install`

Unfortunately this results in this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>     There are no commands defined in the "ckeditor" namespace.

*Using Symfony 3.3-dev, Ckeditor-bundle (5.0.3)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking in https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.rst

I noticed it had changed 14 hours ago, so I compared it to the version Composer had just download 5.0.3, which makes no mention of the `php bin/console ckeditor:install` command.

Switching the version from `^5.0` to `dev-master` in Composer allows `php bin/console ckeditor:install` to work perfectly.

Below is a statement from the repositories owner:

> **egeloen**
>
> The new command (ckeditor:install) will be part of the
>   next 6.x release (probably comming this week) but the online doc is
>   built from master so basically, the doc already exposes this command
>   which is not part of the current stable release (5.x).
>
> Long story short: You can upgrade to 5.x and don't execute the
>   ckeditor:install comand as it is only part of the upcoming 6.x release
>   (not yet released)